# Can we have ng-change globally in anjularjs

Tags: angularjs

There are 5 text boxes in my form and i want to trigger the ng-change when the contents of any text boxes is changed.Now my question is "instead of writing the ng-change 5 times for 5 text boxes, Is there any way to write the ng-change globally i.e in the form tag so that if any text box contents with in the form the corresponding function of ng-change should be triggered

can any one help me please.....

Answer (score 2):

I would make a $watch expression on that part of the model. See the [documentation for $watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with marko that the easiest way is with $watch.

```
$scope.$watch('area1 + area2 + area3 + area4 + area5', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if(oldVal && newVal !== oldVal) {
    console.log('Changed')
  }
});
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VKyx2M?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case when I have a grid with hundreds of inputs, where the inputs are dynamic, and I need to autosave the data after the input has changed

I used the vanilla `onChange` on the wrapper body then checking the target value.

```
<div class="wrapper" onchange="onChangeHanler(event)">
   <input ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="item.value">
</div>
```

In my controller:

```
angular.controller('gridController', function($scope) {         

   // this method belongs to window and not the current $scope, remember we are breaking ng rules here :(
   window.onChangeHandler = function(ev) {  
      console.log(ev.target.value) // print out the value changed                
      queueForAutoSave($scope.items);
   }     
})
```

## PS.

Downvoters I know that this is not the best way to implement this since its againts angular norms, and cause problems to unit tests, etc ..., 
but for now in case of performance it's 100x better than binding the `ng-change` for hundreds of inputs